# How to open a notepad.exe into his session using windows service when even any user logged into the system?

Tags: c#

I want to create a windows service that will automatically trigger notepad.exe into his user session when ever any user logged into the system.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
Process notePad = new Process();
notePad.StartInfo.FileName   = "notepad.exe";
notePad.StartInfo.Arguments = "textFileToDisplay.txt";
notePad.Start();
```

Comment: Dear I had already tried your code and also I had tried  DllImport of CreateProcess function , CreateProcessWithLogonW function and also used Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler functionality but all functionally did not work.

Comment: Can any one solve my problem. Windows service opens notepad in development mode, but when I run windows service using installUtil it does not open notepad. Service starting a process wont show GUI. Notepad is showing is task manager